# How can I search a string with one mistake in a trie?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, bioinformatics, trie

> **Given:** Some large input files containing strings all of the same length k (usually 99 characters) consisting of characters A, G, T, C.
>
> **Task:** Code an algorithm in C that will search for a string of m>k (usually 110) characters such that if the last k-1 characters of a string are the same of the first k-1 of another, these should be concatenated. For example if I'm searching the string `AGTCC` in the set `{AGTC, GTCC}` it will give a positive output.
>
> The algorithm should also output the best exact prefix in case the searched string is not present in the list.
>
> Furthermore, the algorithm should also give positive output if the searched string differs from one present string by one character.

The most clever way I could think of was to organize this huge list in a quaternary (?) tree: each node contains an array of 4 pointers to other nodes, and these are initially NULL. When a character is added, I change the array in the following way: if the input is an A I allocate the 0-th position of the array to a new node with NULL array, if it is C the first one, if G the second, if T the third.

For example, initially the root is `{NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}`. If the first character I add is a C I create a new node N with NULL array, and then I change the root to `{NULL, N, NULL, NULL}`. I explained this to my professor and he stated that this is an actually used data structure called a trie.

I can perform the search and find the best substring in O(m) time with this structure, simply following the tree until I reach a `{NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}` node.

The best way I could think of in order to do the search with the mismatch is to look for every possible single mismatch in the best substring and then perform the whole search again, which gives rise to a complexity of O(4m^2). It's not bad but I'd like to make it linear.

Is there some sort of crazy algorithm that can perform a very efficient single-mismatch search in a trie? Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define k 99
#define m 110 
#define L 10000000 //Check variable in case the input file isn't properly formatted with EOF
typedef struct tree{
  struct tree* base[4];
} node;
int hash(char r){
  if (r=='A') return 0;
  if (r=='C') return 1;
  if (r=='G') return 2;
  if (r=='T'||r=='N') return 3; //Ignore the N bit
  return -1;
}

char invhash(int x){ 
  if (x==0) return 'A';
  if (x==1) return 'C';
  if (x==2) return 'G';
  if (x==3) return 'T';
  return -1;
}

node* newnode(){
  node* new=malloc(sizeof(node));
  for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    new->base[i]=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->base[i]=NULL;
  }
  return new;
}

node* trovak(char* target, node* s, int level){ //Searches a string of length k and outputs a pointer to its leaf if it finds it and NULL otherwise
  if (level==k) return s;
  int h=hash(target[level]);
  if (s->base[h]==NULL){
    return NULL;
  }
  return trovak(target, s->base[h], level+1);
}


void newtree(node* s, char* kmero){ //Adds the string kmero to the tree s
  int h;
  for (int l=0; l<k; l++){
    h=hash(kmero[l]);
    if (s->base[h]==NULL){
      s->base[h]=newnode();
    }
    s=s->base[h];
  }
  return;
}


int trova(char* target, node* s,int level){ //This searches the whole target string in the tree
  if (level==m) return m;
  int h=hash(target[level]);
  if (s->base[h]==NULL){
    printf("There isn't %c (character number %d)\n", invhash(h), level);
    return level;
  }
  return trova(target, s->base[h], level+1);
}

int main(){
  FILE* file=fopen("KAPPA105.txt", "r"); //List of strings file
  FILE* ricerca=fopen("ricerca.txt", "r"); //Target string file
  node* s=newnode(); //Root of tree
  int level=0; //Same as L, don't worry about it
  char* target=malloc(m); //Actual target string
  char* kmero=malloc(k); 
  node* leaf=malloc(sizeof(node)); //Used to build the tree, din't worry about it
  node* linksucc=malloc(sizeof(node)); //Same
  target=fgets(target, m+1, ricerca);
  char* SUCC_KMER=malloc(k); 
  //Creating the tree
  do{
    kmero=fgets(kmero, k+1, file);
    newtree(s, kmero);
    level++;
  } while (fgetc(file)!=EOF&&level<L);
  rewind(file);
  level=0;
  //The tree has always height k, so I attach all the leaves in order to do the concatenation thing
  do{
    leaf=s;
    kmero=fgets(kmero, k+1, file);
    for (int l=0; l<k; l++) leaf=leaf->base[hash(kmero[l])]; 
    strncpy(SUCC_KMER, kmero+1, k-1);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
      SUCC_KMER[k-1]=invhash(i); 
      linksucc=trovak(SUCC_KMER, s, 0); 
      leaf->base[i]=linksucc; /
    }
    level++;
  } while (fgetc(file)!=EOF&&level<L);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //Formatting thing
  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) putchar(target[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) putchar('-');
  putchar('\n');
  int pos=trova(target, s, 0); //Perform the search
  if (pos==m){
    printf("The string is present in the list.\n");
    return 2;
  }
  else{
    printf("Best prefix (%d characters):\n", pos);
    for (int i=0; i<pos; i++) putchar(target[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    //What if there is a single mismatch?????
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `} while (fgetc(file)!=EOF&&level<L);` fgetc() consumes a character from your input.

Comment: I know that, it's a '\n' because of the formatting of the input. The program works, it's just that I don't know how to do the next bit in a clever way.

Comment: `fgets()` also consumes a '\n'. Is there an extra empty line after the line with nucleotides?

Comment: No actually, but I tried just now to make it print the strings it reads and they're correct

Comment: `#define k 99` <<-- please don't do this. Your program will fail terribly if there are shorter/longer lines  in the input.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    new->base[i]=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->base[i]=NULL;
  }
  return new;` <<- you are leaking memory here.

Comment: Why? That's exactly what i want to do

Comment: If you want to store `NULL` in this sentence (`new->base[i]=NULL`), then don't `malloc` anything in the previous line, as you are throwing away the `malloc` result to store `NULL` in its place.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't think I could store NULL in a non allocated pointer

Comment: for the mismatch. Do as you did. Traverse the trie. Now if for some node, your node can't match the current char of the string, try the 3 others char of your node (if not NULL). Only do that the first time since you can have only one mismatch. That's O(m). (like 3*m)

Comment: No, because the search is O(m) and I need to perform it O(4m) times, so that's O(4m^2)

Comment: do that the __first__ time. iterate over your first i chars (if they match). Now one does not match. You have 3 other possibilities. You explore 3 branch corresponding to three substring. Since you can explore any string in O(m), then that's O(3m). If you prefer the total is O(i + 3*(m-i))